# External Id fields not visible in Data Loader UI (they have FLS, aren't read only, can be updated, etc.)

Tags: data-loader

The user is in the System Administrator profile. The fields have FLS (as shown below), which was granted years ago--there is no issue with setting it after logging in. The fields are not read only and is a text field. I have confirmed the user can see and update it through the standard UI and Apex. This is an issue on multiple objects, I've captured screen shots for one below.

Despite this, it is not visible in the Data Loader UI. I have tried logging in/out, both v52 and v54. None of these work. Does anyone know why?

FLS
[image: FLS]

Field
[image: Field]

Data Loader UI
[image: Data Loader UI]

Comment: Are you trying to update the external id field?

Answer (score 1):

Fields not available in Data Loader for Mapping:
Auto-Number fields, Formula fields, and External ID fields are read-only fields that can't be edited or created.

Note: Any fields not added to a page layout will not show up in Data Loader for mapping. All the fields must be added to any of the page layouts for mapping.

Refer the help article [Link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000328431&type=1)